# How to remove/delete texts in Python list from different index position

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have tried several ways to extract the words I want, but I couldn't make it. The completions need to like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzzXkoIWuMAHUjFuT2IteEtLVjQ

After extracting the texts, and then I can put them into CSV file

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

AccessCME=Request('http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/natural-
gas/natural-gas_contract_specifications.html',headers={"User-
Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
CMEPage=uReq(AccessCME).read()
page_soup=soup(CMEPage,"html.parser")

possible_tds=page_soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'prodSpecAtribute'})
parent_td=[td for td in possible_tds if 'Trading' in td.text][0]

Target=parent_td.fetchNextSiblings('td')[1].text

print(Target)

New=Target.split(" ")
print(New)
```

Comment: Which variable gives you the list out of which you'd want to extract the values?

Comment: It will be the variable Target